# SQL Server data not persisted when using Docker volumes

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a dockerized ASP.NET Core 3.0 app, orchestrated using docker-compose. I am developing on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2019.

I would like to persist data in my app's database so that the data in database are preserved at docker restart. Hence, I use a docker volume to mount a path on the image on a host path. I define `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` as the following:

- `docker-compose.yml`:

  ```
  version: '3.4'

  services:

    sql.data:
      container_name: myapp_db
      image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

    myapp:
      container_name: myapp_container
      image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapp
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: myapp.API/Dockerfile
      depends_on:
        - sql.data
  ```
- `docker-compose.override.yml`:

  ```
  version: '3.4'

  services:

    sql.data:
      environment:
        - SA_PASSWORD=Pass_word
        - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      ports:
        - "1433:1433"
      volumes:
        - ${APPDATA}/myapp/Database/mssql:/var/opt/mssql
  ```

Using this `docker-compose*` files, the database does not persist. i.e., when I restart debuging, I get an empty database.

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I fail to reproduce your issue with current steps. Try to check whether `C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\myapp\Database\mssql` is created.

Comment: The folder exists, and every time I add a new entity to the db, I see the size of files increase.

Comment: If so, what do you mean you got an empty database?

Comment: The files seem to be there, but dbcontext does not contain any info for either of the models.